# I am trying to automate a HTML5 video in selenium webdriver with C#

Tags: html, selenium-webdriver, automation

Video doesnt have specific ID, its from youtube. I have tried it using javascript excecutor but not working. the link is : 
http://www.myhomepay.com/Tour/Nanny-Tax-Guide

Answer (score 0):

Hi Parvathy please try it like below it will play the player. only catch here is why its not playing is because its inside the iframe and to perform an operation inside a specific iframe first we have to identify that iframe and then move to that iframe to perform action with webdriver

Hi i am a java guy so posting answer in java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.myhomepay.com/Tour/Nanny-Tax-Guide");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // first identify the play button over the youtube video player

        // Please note youtube palyer is inside the iframe hence first we have 
        // to identify and then switch to the i fame

        List<WebElement> iframe = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
        System.out.println("Total iframe on the webpage is : "+ iframe.size());
        driver.switchTo().frame(iframe.get(0));
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ytp-large-play-button.ytp-button")).click();
    }
```

UPDATE : for C# you can do it like below

```
iFrameElement = Driver.FindElementByTagName("iFrame");
driver = Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(this.iFrameElement);
driver.FindElement(selector);
```

please refactor code as per C#.hope this helps